# Android: Where can I find the code of the native browser app?

Tags: android, browser

I would like to view the source code of the native browser. Where can I find it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Floating around in here, somewhere.](http://android.git.kernel.org/)

[Or, here, more specifically.](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Browser.git;a=summary)

Comment: And the webkit stuff is probably here: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/external/webkit.git;a=summary